# jQuery jscrollpane intermittent reinit

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I am using jQuery jscrollpane on one of the divs with an image inside. It works fine. But when i change the source of that image, sometimes the scrollpane reinits fine, but sometimes it doesn't. It's intermittent, and i am really stuck. Any ideas would be great, thanks!

Init:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#right').jScrollPane({
        verticalDragMinHeight: 10,
        verticalDragMaxHeight: 10,
        horizontalDragMinWidth: 10,
        horizontalDragMaxWidth: 10
    });
...
```

I change the image src with: (and it swaps fine)

```
$("#text-content").attr('src', 'pics/BIOGRAPHY/tretji_stolpec/text_' + sub_menu_images[nav_sec_pos].toLowerCase() + '.png');
```

Then I reinitialize jscrollpane with:

```
var pane_api = $("#right").data('jsp');

pane_api.reinitialise();
```

I have already tried the timeout JS function to reinit jscrollpane, in case there was a problem with lag while changing the src of the image. It didn't work. Any ideas? Cheers, Val

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue trying to load content dinamically, last one on the list of this faq http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/faqs.html

Here is the solution:
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ajax.html

Also note that you have to use the .load method. I tried using .html and .ajax (raw ajax), didn't work.

Cheers, Val

EDIT:
Ok, it reinits fine now, except for the first time it has to show. When the content is loaded dinamically, the first time (sometimes) the scrollpane doesn't show. The next time i load the content dinamically, the scrollpane always shows with no problems..